# Can texdef be forced to show the full definition for environments?

Tags: tools, texdef

When using `texdef` to learn the definitions of environments sometimes not all the relevant lines are shown. I guess this has do with how the definitions are written. It seems that when environments are defined as

```
\def\environmentname{A}
\def\endenvironmentname{B}
```

or as

```
\def\environmentname{A}
\let\endenvironmentname B
```

then `texdef` returns only `A` (and not `B`). Is it possible to make `texdef` return both `A` and `B`? This would make sense because someone who wants to look up a definition of an environment would like to know the definition of the whole environment, i.e. both the beginning and the end.

For example `texdef -t latex equation` returns

```
\equation:
macro:->$$\refstepcounter {equation}
```

when the relevant lines are

```
\def\equation{$$\refstepcounter{equation}}
\def\endequation{\eqno \hbox{\@eqnnum}$$\@ignoretrue}
```

Another example is that `texdef -t latex enumerate` returns

```
\enumerate:
macro:->\ifnum \@enumdepth >\thr@@ \@toodeep \else \advance \@enumdepth \@ne \edef \@enumctr {enum\romannumeral \the \@enumdepth }\expandafter \list \csname label\@enumctr \endcsname {\usecounter \@enumctr \def \makelabel ##1{\hss \llap {##1}}}\fi
```

when the relevant lines are

```
\def\enumerate{%
  \ifnum \@enumdepth >\thr@@\@toodeep\else
    \advance\@enumdepth\@ne
    \edef\@enumctr{enum\romannumeral\the\@enumdepth}%
      \expandafter
      \list
        \csname label\@enumctr\endcsname
        {\usecounter\@enumctr\def\makelabel##1{\hss\llap{##1}}}%
  \fi}
\let\endenumerate =\endlist
```

Comment: The routine could be improved to show also `\endfoo` if not undefined (or equivalent to `\relax`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As stated by egreg environments like `foo` are built by the macros `\foo` and `\endfoo`. `texdef` prints normally the definition of `\foo` if you use `texdef foo`. It does so by using the TeX primitive `\show`, which shows the internal definition, not the original source code. You need to use `texdef foo endfoo` manually to get the definition of both the begin and end code of an environment.

However, starting from `texdef` v1.5 from 2012/04/29 there is now a `--source` / `-s` option which will try to show the original source code of the definition. This is done by first locating the file holding the (first) definition of the macro using the `--find`/`-f` option and then scanning the file for the definition. This works well with most macro definitions both in LaTeX and TeX form, but is not yet implemented for `\newenvironment` etc. and will not/never work with any definitions which change the usual catcodes, i.e. verbatim related macros.

Using this option you can get now get the exact location and source code of e.g. of `enumerate`:

```
$ ./texdef -t latex -s enumerate
% latex.ltx, line 4545:
\def\enumerate{%
  \ifnum \@enumdepth >\thr@@\@toodeep\else
    \advance\@enumdepth\@ne
    \edef\@enumctr{enum\romannumeral\the\@enumdepth}%
      \expandafter
      \list
        \csname label\@enumctr\endcsname
        {\usecounter\@enumctr\def\makelabel##1{\hss\llap{##1}}}%
  \fi}
```

This works because `\def` and not `\newenvironment` was used. Definitions done with `\let` etc. are not supported.
The full file path is given if the `-F` option is used in addition.

Note that at the moment `--source`/`-s` will return nothing if the source is not found. You have to manually remove this option to get the unformatted definition. I will try to improve on this in future versions.

---

#### Update 2011/05/02:

I now released `texdef` v1.6 which supports `\newenvironment` and follows `\let` with the `-s` option. Also, there is now a `-E` option which tells the script that you are asking for an environment. If the `-s` option is used and no LaTeX environment definition is found, or without `-s`, for every `<command>` given as argument an `end<command>` is automatically added.

#### Examples:

```
$ texdef -t latex -s -E enumerate 
% latex.ltx, line 4545:
\def\enumerate{%
  \ifnum \@enumdepth >\thr@@\@toodeep\else
    \advance\@enumdepth\@ne
    \edef\@enumctr{enum\romannumeral\the\@enumdepth}%
      \expandafter
      \list
        \csname label\@enumctr\endcsname
        {\usecounter\@enumctr\def\makelabel##1{\hss\llap{##1}}}%
  \fi}

% latex.ltx, line 4554:
\let\endenumerate =\endlist

% latex.ltx, line 4422:
\def\endlist{%
  \global\advance\@listdepth\m@ne
  \endtrivlist}
```

```
$ texdef -t latex -s abstract
% article.cls, line 376:
  \newenvironment{abstract}{%
      \titlepage
      \null\vfil
      \@beginparpenalty\@lowpenalty
      \begin{center}%
        \bfseries \abstractname
        \@endparpenalty\@M
      \end{center}}%
     {\par\vfil\null\endtitlepage}
```

Here is `-E` option is not required because of `-s` and `\newenvironment`. It doesn't hurt adding it, however.

Answer (score 8):

`texdef` works by feeding the requested macro to TeX with the appropriate format (LaTeX if called with the `-t latex` option). The `foo` environment is actually obtained by defining `\foo` and `\endfoo`, so asking

```
texdef -t latex foo
```

shows the definition of `\foo`. I believe it's feasible that, when the format is LaTeX, `texdef` shows also `\endfoo` if defined. However this might reveal problematic. It's not so difficult to call

```
texdef -t latex foo endfoo
```

(any number of commands can be requested in the command line).